# convert int64 to int32 in pandas.to_numeric()

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with a column with `dtype(int64)` and I want convert it to `int32`. 
when I run code below, I get `dtype(int8)` type but i want get `int32`

```py
pd.to_numeric(x, downcast="integer")
```

how do i do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
df['col'].astype(np.int32)
```

astype doc link: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html

Please have a look at numpy datatype docs: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html

Comment: thanks for your answer and document links